# select QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem by mouseclick in qt

Tags: c++, qt

Helo, in my current project i've faced a problem of selecting QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem in QGraphicsScene , i do the following :

```
QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem* i = canvas.addEllipse(QRectF(-radius,-radius,radius,radius));
i->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
i->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
i->setBrush( QColor(red, green , blue) );
i->setPos(x,y);
i->setZValue(qrand()%256);
```

Where canvas is QGraphicsScene, since i add flag ItemIsMovable , this allows to drag items, but i need to change color of item when the user double clicks them, are there any suggestions?

now the following

```
class MyRectItem : public QObject, public QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    MyRectItem(qreal x, qreal y, qreal w, qreal h) : QGraphicsRectItem(x,y,w,h)
    {}
signals:
    void selectionChanged(bool newState);
protected:
    QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)
    {
        if (change == QGraphicsItem::ItemSelectedChange)
        {
            bool newState = value.toBool();
            emit selectionChanged(newState);
        }
        return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
    }
};
```

and try to call it from here

```
void Main::addCircle(int x, int y,int radius,int red, int green, int blue)
{
    MyRectItem *i = new MyRectItem(-50, -50, 50, 50);
    canvas.addItem(i);
    i->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
    i->setPen(QPen(Qt::darkBlue));
}
```

and get the following error
`../portedcanvas/canvas.cpp: In member function 'void Main::addCircle(int, int, int, int, int, int)':
../portedcanvas/canvas.cpp:233: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'MyRectItem'
../portedcanvas/canvas.cpp:68: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'MyRectItem':
../../../../Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qgraphicsitem.h:331: note:  virtual QRectF QGraphicsItem::boundingRect() const
../../../../Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qgraphicsitem.h:352: note:  virtual void QGraphicsItem::paint(QPainter*, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem*, QWidget*)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `addEllipse` convenience method of QGraphicsScene, subclass your own QGraphicsEllipseItem, and then overload the [`mouseDoubleClickEvent`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qgraphicsitem.html#mouseDoubleClickEvent) to do whatever you want.

All `addEllipse` is doing is creating the object for you and adding it to the scene, then giving you back the pointer. When you create your new instance of your QGraphicsEllipseItem subclass you would either pass the scene to the constructor as the parent, or call `addItem` with your instance on the scene.

**Update**

I'm not a c++ expert, but it seems like in your updated code example you are subclassing the abstract class `QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem` only to add a single overload. That class is abstract for a reason. When you subclass it you are expected to provide the implementation of the various virtual functions, which you are not. What I think you should be doing is  subclassing `QGraphicsEllipseItem` directly like I already suggested.

Comment: @user1280078: I don't think you tried what I actually suggested. You tried something a bit different.

Comment: @user1280078: Just replace QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem with QGraphicsEllipseItem in your subclass. You cant use the abstract class unless you intend on defining all of its abstract/virtual methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [`boundingRect()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect) and [`paint()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#paint) in your class inherited from `QGraphicsItem` (and `QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem` since it doesn't implement them)

But you should just inherit your class from one of the concrete sub-classes like `QGraphicsRectItem` since that's what you actually want your item to behave.